# Time evolution in tensor product Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

Having the Hamiltonian $$H=\beta\left(\sigma^{(1)}_1 -\sigma^{(2)}_1 \right)^2\in\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{(1)}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{(2)},$$
where $$\sigma_1^{(1)}\equiv\sigma_1\otimes 1\!\!1_2, \;\;\; \sigma_1^{(2)}\equiv 1\!\!1_2\otimes\sigma_1,$$ with $1\!\!1_2$ the 2-dimensional identity matrix and
$$\sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$$
how to calculate $$\exp{\left\{-i H t \right\}}\,?$$

***My attempt:*** knowing that $$H=\beta\left(\left(\sigma_1^{(1)}\right)^2 + \left(\sigma_1^{(2)}\right)^2 - 2\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1\right)=2\beta\left( 1\!\!1_4 -\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1 \right),$$ where $1\!\!1_4$ is the 4-dimensional identity matrix, I write $$\exp{\left\{-i H t \right\}}=\exp{\left\{-i\,2\beta\left(1\!\!1_4 -\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1 \right)t\right\}}=$$ $$=\left[1\!\!1_4 \exp{\left\{-i\,2\beta t\right\}}\right] \cdot \exp{\left\{i\,2\beta\left(\sigma_1\otimes\sigma_1\right)t \right\}}=$$ $$=\left[1\!\!1_4 \exp{\left\{-i\,2\beta t\right\}}\right] \cdot \left[\exp{\left\{i\,2\beta\sigma_1 t\right\}}\otimes\exp{\left\{i\,2\beta\sigma_1 t\right\}} \right].$$

Is it correct?

Comment: That last split of the exponential of $i 2 \beta \, \sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_1$ is wrong.

Comment: You get instead $\exp \left[i 2 \beta t \, \sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_1  \right] \, = \, \cos \left(2 \beta t  \right) \, 1_{4 \times 4} \, + \,  i \sin \left(2 \beta t  \right) \, \sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_1 $.

Comment: @secavara Obvious as it is, perhaps you should collect your two comments in an answer, if the OP does not withdraw the question...

Comment: @secavara, How can I prove it?

Comment: @Cosmas, How can I prove it?

Comment: $(\sigma_1\otimes \sigma_1)^2 =1\!\! 1\otimes 1\!\! 1$ , so look at the Taylor series of the exponential, odd and even parts.